# Error en el método OnItemClickListener()

Tags: java, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estoy trabajando con Android Studio y al colocar el método `OnItemClickListener()` me sale remarcado con error y no entiendo la razón, lo que quería lograr era que al tener un listView al presionar algún nombre nos diga la edad.

```
package com.example.asus.listview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tv1;
    private ListView lv1;

    private String nombres [] = {"Jonathan", "Marco", "Cristian", "Esteban", "Paz", "Daisy", "Manuel",
            "Luis", "Uriel", "Alan"};
    private String edades [] = {"19", "18", "19", "19", "21", "19", "21", "22", "22", "20"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);

        ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_app, nombres);
        lv1.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long 1) {
                tv1.setText("La edad de " + lv1.getItemAtPosition(i) + " es " + edades[i] + "años" );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué el tercer parámetro en lo que viene siendo la función de tu línea 34 es un  `long 1 `?

Comment: Ohh si, ya veo cual era el error, en ves de "1" es "l" que error mas tonto, bueno creo que ya no me volverá a ocurrir.

Comment: Si te ha funcionado, vota mi respuesta hacia arriba, saludos. Esperemos que no te vuelva a pasar. :)